# How do I configure the Out Of Process Session Provider? (ASP.NET - IIS7)

Tags: asp.net

I'd like to experiment with the out of process session provider in ASP.NET/IIS7 (non-in memory). I understand that then a different process is taking care of my session state, so that I could restart the application domain/w3wp without losing session information.

However, how do I set this up, preferably pretty much transparent to my web application?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Please see [Configuring Out-of-Process Session State with the ASP.NET State Service (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/76740cd5-7a40-4aa8-8de4-6f1f10c90633.mspx?mfr=true):

> If you decide to manage session state
>   by using the ASP.NET state service,
>   you must determine whether you are
>   going to maintain session state for a
>   Web garden or a Web farm. Then you
>   need to ensure that the ASP.NET state
>   service (Aspnet_state.exe) is running
>   and, that it is configured to start
>   automatically.

Comment: I have IIS 7 (added this info to my question).